# Hasura: Rename relationship fields

Tags: hasura

I have renamed my GQL root fields, which works as described in the documentation.

Unfortunately, these names do not seem to be applied to relations - is this a bug or simply not possible?

Example: Two entities, "Categories" and "Projects", connected by a one-to-many relationship. I renamed the aggregation root fields to "CategoriesAggregate" and "ProjectsAggregate", which works as expected.

However, in the query "Catgeories" (select all) I am offered "Projects_aggregate" as available relationship, not "ProjectsAggregate" as expected.

Here is an example query to illustrate it:

```
query MyQuery {
  Categories {
    Projects_aggregate {
      aggregate {
        count
      }
    }
    id
  }
  ProjectsAggregate {
    aggregate {
      count
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to adjust this?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look on https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/3207 . Is it the same problem ?

Comment: In fact, this seems to be the same issue in the result. In that case, it is apparently not possible at the moment.

Thanks!